# Anaconda issue, DLL load failed

Tags: python, anaconda

I installed Anaconda on my machine yesterday and installed the Anaconda Extention Pack in VSC, when I try this:

Code:

```py
import numpy as ny
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:/Python/Testing/VSC with Anaconda/packagetest.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as ny
  File "E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
    from . import _distributor_init
  File "E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py", line 34, in <module>   
    from . import _mklinit
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Please help me fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very common reason for this error is that the **conda environment hasn't been properly activated**. This can be done by either using the "Anaconda prompt" or by e.g. starting the cmd shell and then running `C:\users\user_name>conda activate`. This will change the prompt to `(base) C:\users\user_name>` and add serveral Anaconda subfolders to the PATH. Then Python should be started from there via `(base) C:\users\user_name> python`. Without activation numpy won't find it's DLL's.

Comment: This worked for me, thank you! Apparently on Windows, starting Spyder as an App over the search bar results in the environment not being activated correctly, so I'll stick to my .bat file from now on.